# Write field value to embedded form

Tags: javascript, html

I would have thought that this would be an easy task but for some reason I can't get it working. I have a [FormCraft](https://formcraft-wp.com/) form embedded in my webpage which contains a hidden field. I would like to write the value of that field from a variable.

HTML of the form:

```
              <div class="form-page  form-page-1 form-page-last elements-count-17" style="">
                                   
                <div class="is-page      ">
                  <div class="form-element  form-element-type-text required-false default-visible  " data-field="field33" style="width: 100%; flex-basis: 100%;">
                    <div class="form-field"><input type="hidden" class="trigger-logic " name="field33" value="" autocomplete="off"><div class="text-cover-compile "><p class=""><img src="https://formcrafts.com/file/view/d0b2560bd4dad6910239825c34e51adb/Application%20header" alt=""></p></div></div>
                    
                  </div><div class="form-element  form-element-type-one-line-text required-true default-visible  " data-field="field15" style="width: 50%; flex-basis: 50%;">
                    <div class="form-field"><label class=""><span class="label-cover"><span class="label ">First Name<span class="asterisk "></span></span><span class="sub-label "></span></span><span class="field-input-cover"><input aria-label="First Name" type="text" class="trigger-logic " name="field15" tooltip="" title="" placeholder="" data-input-validate="none" data-input-mask=""></span></label></div>
                 
                    
                  </div><div class="form-element  form-element-type-hidden required-false default-visible  " data-field="field23" style="width: 100%; flex-basis: 100%;">
                    <div class="form-field"><div class="field-input-cover "><span class="label ">utm_campaign</span><span class="sub-label">Hidden Field</span><input type="hidden" class="trigger-logic trigger-math" name="field23" value="" autocomplete="off"></div></div>
                    
                    
                  </div><div class="form-element  form-element-type-submit required-false default-visible  " data-field="field12" style="width: 100%; flex-basis: 100%;">
                    <div class="form-field"><button aria-label="CONTINUE" type="submit" class="button form-button submit-button "><span class="submit-button-text trigger-math ">CONTINUE</span><span style="border-color: ; border-left-color: transparent" class="loader loader-white"></span></button><div class="submit-response "></div></div>
                    
                  </div>
                </div>                  
              </div>
            <div class="rg-right"><span></span></div><div class="rg-left"><span></span></div></div>
```

And I'm trying to populate the field 'utm_campaign' using this simple script:

```
<script>
  document.querySelector("[data-field='field23']").value = {{cookie - utm_campaign}};
</script>
```

I've tried a number of methods and I can't get it to work. I can see that the script is firing and that the variable is properly assigned. It just isn't making its way into the field for form submission.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.